# Android Client - Server Program

Tags: java, android, client-server

Hello Im able to send message from Client to Server but unable to receive the message from the Server to client and display it can you please correct my mistake here? Im not sure if im receiving the data from server or not I tried debugging

Android Client

```
package com.revolve.bhuvanesh.android_client_server;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter,printwriterI;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;
    private String recMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //---------------

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the text field
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send button

        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
                textField.setText(recMsg);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, recMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //----------------


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            try {

                client = new Socket("192.168.1.235", 2288); // connect to the server
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream




                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String message = br.readLine();

                recMsg=message;


                ois.close();
                client.close(); // closing the connection
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

    }




}
```

Server Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;



public class SimpleTextServer {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar";  
       static final String DB_URL = "";
       static final String USER = "";
       static final String PASS = "";


    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
           Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2288); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        while (true)
        {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write("Hey Client");
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is ");
                bw.flush();


            oos.writeObject("Checking...");
            clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }



        try{
              //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

              //STEP 3: Open a connection
              System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
              System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            /*  //STEP 4: Execute a query
              System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");*/
              stmt = conn.createStatement();

              String sql = "update msg set message='"+message+"' where id = 0";

              stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

           }catch(SQLException se){
              //Handle errors for JDBC
              se.printStackTrace();
           }catch(Exception e){
              //Handle errors for Class.forName
              e.printStackTrace();
           }finally{
              //finally block used to close resources
              try{
                 if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }// do nothing
              try{
                 if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }//end finally try
           }//end try
           System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well in your debug for errors the port is not `4444` but in fact `2288` You should construct the `Input & Output Streams` together... just to avoid the mess of a code you have

Comment: Please read the [ask] section. Do not just dump code, try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Im sorry im aware of that 4444 and 2288. I just didnt change it. What im asking is how I send the data from server to client and display it on the client side? Could you please help me?